# Joda DateTime automatically change timezone when parsing string

Tags: java, jodatime

I have string of a date in "iso8601" format and when I parse it using Joda "DateTime", the time zone of date changes automatically.

```
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2017-05-22T08:10:00.000+0300" ) ;
  System.out.println(dateTime);
```

and its output is:

```
2017-05-22T09:40:00.000+04:30
```

As you see time zone of first string is +3:00 and the time zone after parsing is +04:30. How can I parse first string without changing time zone? (so the time zone remains +03:00 even after parsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This constructor use default timezone of user. You need to set timezone manually with `DateTime(Object object, DateTimeZone zone)` construnctor.

Or, parse this string with usage of `withOffsetParsed()` like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime("2017-05-22T08:10:00.000+0300");
```

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer. I have same problem with SimpleDateFormat when i try to serialize my object to xml? do you know how can I solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup time zone manually something like this:

```
String str =  "2017-05-22T08:10:00.000+0300" ;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime() ;

System.out.println(dateTime);
String tzName = str.substring(text.length() - 5);
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneDateTimeZone forID(str.substring(3) + ":" + str.substring(text.length() - 2))
System.out.println(dateTime.withZone(tz));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt functionalities of JDK 8 date-time API to solve this easily. The following code prints 2017-05-22T08:10+03:00.

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ;
OffsetDateTime date1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-05-22T08:10:00.000+03:00", df);
System.out.println(date1); //prints 2017-05-22T08:10+03:00
```

Comment: unfortunately i have to stick with JDK7!!